# MVC 4 Add/Update list in a partial view

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my first program and I am quite not sure on how to complete my codes. I am trying to create a new transaction, where for a supplier there will be multiple inventory types. I am lost on how to add the inventory types to a list using Partial View. Any guidance on how to structure the code will be greatly appreciated. Here are my codes:

**ViewModels:**

```
public class InventoryTransactionParent
    {
        [Key]
        public int InventoryTransactionID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("InventoryTransactionType")]
        [Display(Name = "Transaction Type")]
        public int InventoryTransactionTypeID { get; set; }
        public virtual InventoryTransactionType InventoryTransactionType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Supplier")]
        [ForeignKey("Supplier")]
        public int? SupplierID { get; set; }
        public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Transaction Date (From previous month only)")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime InventoryTransactionDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Receipt/Invoice No.")]
        public string InventoryTransactionReceipt { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Transaction By")]
        public string InventoryTransactionBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Created On")]
        public DateTime InventoryTransactionCreatedDateTime { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Created By")]
        public string InventoryTransactionCreatedBy { get; set; }

        public bool InventoryTransactionCancelled { get; set; }
        public int? InventoryTransactionCancelledSourceID { get; set; }

        public List<InventoryTypeChild> InventoryTypeChilds { get; set; }
    }

public class InventoryTypeChild
    {
        [ForeignKey("InventoryType")]
        [Display(Name = "Inventory Type")]
        public int InventoryTypeID { get; set; }
        public virtual InventoryType InventoryType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
        public decimal InventoryTransactionQuantity { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Price per Item")]
        public decimal InventoryTransactionPrice { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remarks (1000 characters)")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string InventoryTransactionRemarks { get; set; }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model Inventory.ViewModels.InventoryTransactionParent
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)



  <fieldset>
        <legend>In Transaction</legend>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierID, "Supplier")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("SupplierID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InventoryTransactionDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InventoryTransactionDate, "TransactionDate")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InventoryTransactionReceipt)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InventoryTransactionReceipt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InventoryTransactionReceipt)
        </div>
        <div id="inventorytypes">
            @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.InventoryTypeChilds[0].InventoryTypeID)</td>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.InventoryTypeChilds[0].InventoryTransactionPrice)</td>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.InventoryTypeChilds[0].InventoryTransactionQuantity)</td>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.InventoryTypeChilds[0].InventoryTransactionRemarks)</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                @{
                    if (Model.InventoryTypeChilds != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Model.InventoryTypeChilds.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DropDownList("InventoryTypeID", String.Empty)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InventoryTypeChilds[i].InventoryTypeID)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.InventoryTypeChilds[i].InventoryTransactionPrice)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.InventoryTypeChilds[i].InventoryTransactionPrice)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.InventoryTypeChilds[i].InventoryTransactionQuantity)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.InventoryTypeChilds[i].InventoryTransactionQuantity)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.InventoryTypeChilds[i].InventoryTransactionRemarks)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.InventoryTypeChilds[i].InventoryTransactionRemarks)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                }
                </table>
            }
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="In" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller** (still very rough):

```
public ActionResult InMultipleTransaction()
        {
            ViewBag.InventoryTypeID = new SelectList(db.InventoryTypes, "InventoryTypeID", "InventoryTypeName");
            ViewBag.SupplierID = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "SupplierName");
            InventoryTransactionParent itp = new InventoryTransactionParent();
            itp.InventoryTypeChilds = new List<InventoryTypeChild>();
            itp.InventoryTypeChilds.Add(new InventoryTypeChild()
            {

            });

            return View(itp);
        }
```

Comment: am I even heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Partial Views` in `one-to-many` relationship. `Partial Views` are useful if parent and child objects are being created at the same time, mostly happens in `one-to-one` relationship (But even then, most people use ViewModels). But in your case, you have to have parent object created first then you add many child objects.

[This Plural Sight video would be a good way to start. There is a free trial](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mvc4)

Comment: Hi, my requirement requires me to create parent and child at the same time. Hence I need to keep the list in cache until it is submitted to the database. Therefore I think something like Partial Views

Comment: @blurryMVC I think you need to revisit your application design requirements. We are talking about infinite number of `Child Objects`. You cannot create them at the same time as `Parent Object`, atleast not to my knowledge.

Comment: Ic, thanks I'll try to take a look. I have some related question though, I tried to submit with only 1 member in the List. However the controller doesn't capture @Html.DropDownList("InventoryTypeID", String.Empty) value. Is there something I missed?

Comment: @blurryMVC That is enough for another question, mention it here when you ask and i will try to help.

Comment: I found out the issue. I should use DropDownListFor instead DropDownList. Thx!

Comment: @blurryMVC good, also here is one of the answers i gave a while back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441127/populating-and-selecting-a-drop-down-list-value-in-asp-net-mvc-4/15445440#15445440